# Launch cocoa application for all users during login

Tags: macos, cocoa, shell, launchd, osascript

I want to launch myapp.app during login time and it should work for all users.

I tried with osascript which launch only for a user who run that command .

/usr/bin/osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to make a new login item with properties {path : "Path/myapp.app" hidden:false name:"myapp"} at end "

I ran this log-in as a guser .So it launches during login of only guser .

And even i tried with 
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/loginwindow AutoLaunchedApplicationDirectory -array-add '{ "Path" ="path1" ; "Hide"="0";}'

When path1=myapp.app it didnt worked
When path1=myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp it is launching for all users but even a terminal window is launching along with the application .

I have a shell script from that i have to some command that launches cocoa app for all users login time.
Please help .

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449135/how-can-a-cocoa-application-add-itself-as-a-global-login-item

Comment: For information about why `sudo defaults write` doesn't work, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483959/osx-10-8-loginitems

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LSSharedFileList](http://cocoatutorial.grapewave.com/tag/lssharedfilelist-h/) API.
Take a look at [How can a Cocoa application add itself as a global login item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449135/how-can-a-cocoa-application-add-itself-as-a-global-login-item) and [Register as Login Item with Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608963/register-as-login-item-with-cocoa)

Take a look at [Technical Note TN2083](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2083/_index.html)(Global Login Item)

> A global login item is a login item that is launched when any user
>   logs in. Installing a global login item is roughly equivalent to
>   installing that login item for all users on the system: every time a
>   user logs in, loginwindow launches that user's login items and all
>   global login items.